# angular filtering nested objects: AND vs OR

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I'm using angular filtering from Controller level, i.e. `filterFilter`. I need to implement nested filtering and I'm not sure how to do that in angular the best way.

I've got a collection of objects that look like the following:

```
{
  "id": "5d004ff4-46a9-47d5-b068-6b9d581bb6fa",
  "number": 80501703098,
  "firstName": "Loma",
  "lastName": "Collins",
  "age": 44,
  "birthDate": "1980-08-21T12:40:47.026Z",
  "address": {
    "street": "2209 Hirthe Plains",
    "city": "North Heathertown",
    "postCode": "24805"
  },
  "email": {
    "home": "Josefa49@yahoo.com",
    "work": "Phoebe64@sdc.dk"
  },
  "phone": {
    "mobile": "+82 763 681 802",
    "home": "(453) 312 255 267",
    "work": "+45 843 108 216"
  }
}
```

I also have a form that accepts several plain text inputs and the code of the controller:

```
XyzModule.run(['filterFilter', function(filterFilter){
  data = ... // above collection
  params = ... // data from the form
  filtered = filterFilter(data, {
    number: params.number,
    lastName: params.lastName,
    firstName: params.firstName
  });
});
// this has been manually transpiled from .coffee
// don't pay attention if there are errors in the syntax
```

Above code can successfully find collection objects by `number`, `lastName` and `firstName` - that's fine.

---

Now I want to search by `email` and `phone`. The case here is that the search form accepts plain text fields: phone is just a string as well as email is. But the objects in the collection have nested phone and nested email values.

I want to implement **filtering data, where object is matched when params.email is either email.home OR email.work**. Analogically, when params.phone is **either** phone.mobile **OR** phone.home **OR** home.work. `params` is the map of search form input values.

I tried something like:

```
  filtered = filterFilter(data, {
    phone: params.phone,
    email: params.email
  });
```

but it doesn't work, probablt the format is invalid.

```
  filtered = filterFilter(data, {
    phone: {
      home: params.phone,
      mobile: params.phone,
      work: params.phone
    },
    email: {
      home: params.email,
      work: params.email
    }
  });
```

doesn't work either, because it applies **AND** instead of **OR** and it's impossible to have the same value for different phones or for different emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$` wildcard:

```
filtered = filterFilter(data, {
  phone: {
    $: params.phone
  },
  email: {
    $: params.email
  }
});
```

Comment: OP, I would quite like to know if this works, because I rolled my own solution for this problem and it would be nice to know if it was a massive waste of time...